# Whats the right way to publish an Alpha / Beta Android App?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm just getting started with writing Android apps.

I have something I want to make available to a few interested testers, but I'm a long way from having an app. ready for the general public.

How do I make it available for testers without putting it on Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a developer account, you can upload the app for testing, visible only a limited audience. This can be done without publishing the app on Play Appstore for the general public.

Google recommends [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for Beta-testing and staged rollouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to this website: http://thebetafamily.com/

On this website, both testers and creators car register. Testers will apply for tests (tests can be paid or not) and app creators can register to present their app and explain what specific parts of the website should be tested: http://thebetafamily.com/features.

I got really good feedbacks from testers there, both functional and technical, even though I did not offer any paid tests for now.

There is also TestFlight: https://testflightapp.com/ but the difference is that you have to gather your own testers team (I did not have a real network of testers to provide ...).